# How Can I Replace Text Between Slashes On Notepad?

Tags: notepad++

Can I Reploace Text Between Slashes On Notepad 
Like :
files/ballistic-biscuit/ballistic-biscuit.jpg
Replace It With 
files/ballistic-biscuit.jpg
But It is not the same line Form
It like 
files/bomb_darts/bomb_darts.jpg
And
files/cootie/cootie.swf

Plz Help Me

Answer (score 3):

You have a file that contains path information text in the following format:

```
files/ballistic-biscuit/ballistic-biscuit.jpg
files/bomb_darts/bomb_darts.jpg
files/cootie/cootie.swf
```

You want to remove the intermediate directory from file path.  The filename minus the extension is the same as the intermediate directory that you want to remove.

```
files/ballistic-biscuit/ballistic-biscuit.jpg
```

becomes

```
files/ballistic-biscuit.jpg
```

In other words, the intermediate directory name is the same as the filename without the extension.

Use the regex find/replace mode to find and select everything between the slashes including the slashes.  Then replace with one slash.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/notepad-plus/forums/forum/331754/topic/4686065

Use this:
[image: Notepad++ regex]

Comment: I Can't Understant The Soluttion plz explain it ..
the solution is: \Start.*\End Other exemple: \(.*\)

Comment: See the screenshot above.  The regex you want to use is

    [/].*[/]